# Is this code for Miller-Rabin test wrong? (answer for the exercise for 1.28 in SICP)

Tags: scheme, sicp

I was trying to solve exercise 1.28 in SICP, about Miller-Rabin algorithm, after which I found an answer online, but I think the answer was wrong. I come to ask if it's wrong.

He checks if `(remainder (square base) m)=1` while doing expmod loops. However, when doing loops the base and m will stay constantly, which means he is doing the same check, and it's not what the Miller-Rabin Test want to do.

```
(define (expmod base exp m)
  (cond ((= exp 0)
         1)
        ((nontrivial-square-root? base m) 
         0)
        ((even? exp)
         (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m))
                    m))
        (else
         (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m))
                    m))))

(define (nontrivial-square-root? a n)
  (and (not (= a 1))
       (not (= a (- n 1)))
       (= 1 (remainder (square a) n))))
```

if `n=k*2^c`, I think we should check if `(remainder (a^(k*2*(c-1))) n)=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what it is supposed to be doing.  The procedure `expmod` is supposed to compute the exponential of a number modulo another number, the only difference this time is that you check for a nontrivial square root every time it recurses.  `m` will stay constant during the `expmod` procedure, and the `miller-rabin` procedure you write will run `expmod` with a random number `m` every time.

Happy coding!

By the way, good luck with SICP!  I'm on excersise 2.45 right now, it gets easier (although there are some very abstract concepts).